# About the speed of light

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, reference-frames, rocket-science

If Mr. E is aboard a spaceship traveling near the speed of light the usual reason for the spaceship not going faster than $c$ is the (relativistic) mass of the ship increases without bound, I think. Yet Mr. E says out loud what about the mass of the fuel? When the fuel's (relativistic) mass increases would its potential energy increase enough to compensate for the ship's (relativistic) mass increase?

Comment: See [relativistic rocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_rocket).

Comment: Also a crucial point is that speeds are *relative*. From the referance frame of the rocket, it is not moving and it's mass is just it's normal rest mass.

Comment: The other crucial point is that the actual reason for it not going faster than $c$ is the addition of velocity formula prevents you from accelerating above it

Comment: The actual reason for the rocket under consideration not going faster than $c$ (i.e. maximum signal speed) between a given starting gate and a given finish line is of course that the rocket also presents a signal having been sent from starting gate to finish line (and not even necessarily a signal of the highest speed). p.s. Concerning the well-known formula for adding speeds in the same direction it is worth noting that $\frac{u + v}{1 + u \, v} > 1$ for instance if $ v > 1 > u > 0$.

Comment: Considering this situation if the mass of the ship increased relative to observers on Earth , would the mass of the fuel increase relative to the Earth observers, and subsequently would the potential energy of the fuel increase relative to Earth observers?

Comment: If the mass of the ship ( as it was accelerating towards c) increased relative to the Earth , would the mass of the fuel increase relative to the Earth observers?